# google maps - track click event on info window content

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-analytics

my google map code is:

```
function initialize(mapdata){
    var LatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(mapdata[0],mapdata[1]);
    var myOptions= {
        zoom:16,
        scaleControl:true,
        streetViewControl:false,
        panControl:true,
        mapTypeControl:true,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(mapdata[0],mapdata[1]),
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    document.getElementById("map").style.height="200px";
    document.getElementById("map").style.width="450px";
    var infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:LatLng});
    marker.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
        infowindow.setContent(<div style="text-align:right; font-size:8pt; color:black;">click here<a href="http://www.google.com/"></a> </div>');
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

my question is how can I track with analytics after a click event in the info window content?

Thanks in advance,
Irena

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [analytics Event Tracking Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

also note that your `infowindow.setContent(<div...` misses a `'` before `('<div`

**UPDATE**

to set the onclick event on the link within the infowindow, you have to use the jquery live event. This because the link isn't present untill we've clicked on the marker to show the infowindow.

so to implement the click event on the `<div>` within the info window you want to do something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
        infowindow.setContent('<div style="text-align:right; font-size:8pt; color:black;" id="some_id_here">click here<a href="http://www.google.com/"></a> </div>');
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
$("#some_id_here").live('click', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

mind that i've given the div the `id="some_id_here"`

if you have multiple infowindow's that open at the same time, you need to unbind the live event before resetting it. Else it's possible that the `live('click')` event is binded multiple times. To achieve this you should do this:

```
$("#some_id_here").die('click').live('click', function() {
```

Comment: thanks but I already know how to track events in analytics. the problem is that i don't know how to implement the on click event in the info window code